# Remove rows in Dataframe if they match second dataframe based on index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which includes some "invalid" rows, which I would like to remove. I have a second dataframe which contains these invalid rows.

the invalid rows are =

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-11', '2019-12-06', '2019-12-13', '2019-12-15',
           '2019-12-17', '2019-12-18', '2019-12-19', '2019-12-31',
           '2020-01-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', '2020-01-10',
           '2020-01-15', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-22', '2020-02-05',
           '2020-02-07', '2020-02-09', '2020-02-10', '2020-02-12',
           '2020-02-14', '2020-02-19', '2020-02-20', '2020-02-21',
           '2020-02-25', '2020-02-26', '2020-02-28', '2020-03-02',
           '2020-03-04', '2020-03-06', '2020-03-11', '2020-03-12',
           '2020-03-15', '2020-03-22', '2020-03-29', '2020-04-04',
           '2020-04-11', '2020-04-13', '2020-05-13', '2020-05-23',
           '2020-05-29', '2020-05-30', '2020-06-12', '2020-06-15',
           '2020-06-19', '2020-06-24', '2020-06-26', '2020-07-09',
           '2020-07-10', '2020-07-11', '2020-07-12', '2020-07-16',
           '2020-07-17', '2020-07-18', '2020-07-20', '2020-07-23',
           '2020-07-24', '2020-07-26'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='dateTime', freq=None)
```

I want to removes these rows (dates) from:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-11 11:00:00', '2019-11-11 12:00:00',
           '2019-11-11 13:00:00', '2019-11-11 14:00:00',
           '2019-11-11 15:00:00', '2019-11-11 16:00:00',
           '2019-11-11 17:00:00', '2019-11-11 18:00:00',
           '2019-11-11 19:00:00', '2019-11-11 20:00:00',
           ...
           '2020-07-26 05:00:00', '2020-07-26 06:00:00',
           '2020-07-26 07:00:00', '2020-07-26 08:00:00',
           '2020-07-26 09:00:00', '2020-07-26 10:00:00',
           '2020-07-26 11:00:00', '2020-07-26 12:00:00',
           '2020-07-26 13:00:00', '2020-07-26 14:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='dateTime', length=6196, freq='H')
```

I tried :

```
df_steps1h.loc[df_steps1h.index.difference(df_valid.index), ]
```

and

```
df_steps1h[~df_steps1h.index.isin(df_valid.index)].dropna()
```

The DataFrames are different, so I dont want to use concat or merge.
but it doesn't remove anything. Any ideas as to why ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering **df** as the invalid rows DataFrame and **df_valid** as the original DataFrame from which you want to remove.

```
df_valid.loc[:,"actual_index"]=df_valid.index
df_valid.loc[:,"actual_index"]=df_valid.loc[:,"actual_index"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
df_valid.loc[:,"actual_index"]=pd.to_datetime(df_valid.loc[:,"actual_index"])
df_valid=df_valid[~df_valid.actual_index.isin(df.index)]
df_valid.drop('actual_index', inplace=True, axis=1)
```

In the mentioned query, though the index of the DataFrame is of type **DatetimeIndex** but the values are significantly different from the other DataFrame based on **Frequency**.

The solution aims at converting it to a similar frequency and hence perform operation.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering, I tried running your code, but it doesn't remove any rows :/

Comment: Please try after the edit. I've changed this line `df_valid=df_valid[~df_valid.actual_index.isin(df.index)]`

Comment: now I get :A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  errors=errors,

Comment: But I do also still need the dataframe to contain info on every hour

Comment: Hey! I changed `df_valid=df_valid[~df_valid.index.isin(df.index)]` and it works

Comment: The df_valid dataframe still can have info for every hour. We are just creating a temporary datetime column `actual_index` which has the same frequency as that of the other dataframe.